# SSRS 2012 report rendering on IE11

Tags: sql-server-2012, internet-explorer-11, ssrs-2012

I developed reports in SSRS 2012. Users view reports using IE11 (version 11.0.9600.18537). I set the report columns visible(Column headers) while scrolling. It works fine in the reportviewer but when I deploy it to the report manager header(report column headers) does not scroll anymore. On the IE 11 I tried to change the document mode to 10 and it works fine. But upon refresh it goes away. Now fixing the browser is hard as we may have to make a policy change across the company which is no go.

Please suggest a SSRS server side fix.

Already tried the server side fix. But failed to work.
https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3666/sql-server-reporting-services-ssrs-is-not-compatible-with-internet-explorer-11/
As a matter of fact I don't even have the suggested meta tag in the "reportviewer.aspx" but I tried to add it anyway with no success of working.

I expect column headers to be visible while scrolling on IE11 on SSRS 2012 report manager. Since we own SSRS 2012 report manager and I have admin access I can try to make changes in that server.

Answer (score 0):

Found the fix, under "ReportManager\Pages\Report.aspx" there is the tag which I modified from content="IE=Edge" to content="IE=5"

to